# CSS: fit relative positioned parent to height of absolute positioned child

Tags: css, positioning

I am trying to build a simple slideshow. So far, the basic markup looks like this:

```
<h1>My Slideshow</h1>

<p>This paragraph behaves as expected.</p>

<div class="slide-container">
  <div class="slide">
    <h2>First Slide</h2>
    <p>Some stuff on this slide…</p>
  </div>

  <div class="slide">
    <h2>Second Slide</h2>
    <p>And some more stuff here…</p>
  </div>
</div>

<p>This paragraph will disappear beneath the stacked images.</p>
```

This is the corresponding CSS:

```
.slide-container {
  position: relative;
}

.slide {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;

  /* just for the looks */
  width: 20em;
  padding: 0 1em;
  border: 1px solid steelblue;
  background: white;
}
```

The problem is, that the `.slide-container` does not fit to the height of its child (or children) `.slide` (see screenshot).

[image]

I know i can set the height of the `.slide-container` manually, but i want to put this in a fluid grid, where the height is variable. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Unfortunately, absolutely positioned elements are just that:  Positioned absolutely where you told the browser to put it.  This kind of positioning removes the element from the document flow.

Comment: so i guess setting the height manually would be the only solution, am i right?

Comment: or is there another way to stack the `.slide`s on top of each other, without using `position: absolute;` ?

Comment: Is there are more modern solution than answers we have now?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Absolutely-positioned items are logically-associated with their parent, but not "physically". They're not part of the layout, so the parent item can't really see how big they are. You need to code the size yourself, or sniff it with JavaScript and set it at run-time.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this using jquery:

```
    function sliderheight(){
        divHeight = $('.slide').height();
        $('.slide-container').css({'height' : divHeight});
    }
    sliderheight();
```

This will resize the 'slide-container' div to have the same height as the 'slide' div.

You can make it responsive by calling the function on the firing of a 'resize' event:

```
   $(window).resize(sliderheight);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Perfect way of doing this is to set the relative parent's dimensions i.e. height & width to fit the absolute children.

http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/detailed-css-positioning/

This guy wrote enough to understand the basics of css positioning. Actually the relative parent is used to position all its absolute child logically. But it does not share the physical position as a result it does not stretch itself to cover the relative children.