# Anchor tag not taking full height inside absolutely positioned div

Tags: css

```css
.box {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 500px;
}

.one {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  left: 1px;
  top: 1px;
}

.two {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  right: 1px;
  top: 1px;
}
```

```html
<a href="" class="box">
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
</a>
```

The anchor tag not taking full height inside absolutely positioned div. How can I fix that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS: fit relative positioned parent to height of absolute positioned child](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577090/css-fit-relative-positioned-parent-to-height-of-absolute-positioned-child)

Comment: there is no `a` tag inside the absolutely positioned DIVs

Answer (score 0):

This is never going to work, because absolute positioned elements are removed from the 'normal' html-flow