# Clearing div -- odd CSS position bug

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm designing section titles that are half one font and half another, e.g.:

[image: example]

I accomplished this in code with the following HTML and CSS:

```
<div class="section-title">
  <div id="about-title-left" class="section-title-left">
    abo
  </div>
  <div id="about-title-right-outer" class="section-title-right-outer">
    <div class="section-title-right-inner">
      out
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.section-title {
  position: relative;
}
.section-title-left {
  font: 300 85px Lato, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  text-align: right;
  right: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 7px;
}
.section-title-right-outer {
  font: 100px Baskerville, serif;
  text-align: left;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.section-title-right-inner {
  float: right;
}
```

However, when I add *another* such section title, it overlaps with the first one. I've been staring at this for hours, and I can't figure out why it's happening. I don't have the overlapping problem if I replace the title with simple text, but as soon as I add the rest it breaks. Can anyone figure this out?

[Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/wgeb1fp5/2/) a fiddle that shows overlapping titles.

Comment: You should probably show another piece of code in which you have two titles, in order that the code can demonstrate your problem. Think "*[mcve]*."

Comment: @DavidThomas It has two tiles..

Comment: @Mr.Alien: the question shows the left and right components of one title; but there doesn't seem to be a second title which, from my reading of the question, is where the problem is demonstrated. I may be misunderstanding the question though.

Comment: @DavidThomas Good point, I edited the question by adding a JSFiddle with two overlapping titles.

Comment: @DavidThomas Ok, you were right. My bad, I misunderstood the question.

Comment: @Mr.Alien: no problem; I misread almost as often as I read correctly, so being questioned is usually welcome and helps everyone! :) Liam: the problem may be that you're using the same `id` multiple times in the same document; an `id` ***must*** be unique within the document; so instead of using an `id` selector use the class name(s) to select elements appropriately.

Comment: @liammccarty The problem is, that the `.section-title` has no height, since their children have `position: absolute` the parents do not receive their height. You have to define a height for the `.section-title` or have to find an other solution for the children instead of `position: absolute`. [CSS: fit relative positioned parent to height of absolute positioned child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577090/css-fit-relative-positioned-parent-to-height-of-absolute-positioned-child)

Comment: @MA-Maddin That works! Thank you so much